# TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null - error during setState

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to set state in componentWillMount after a dispatch call.
Its throwing error that `TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null`

Its working in one of my page but throwing error in this one.

```
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            historyList: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        return this.context.store.dispatch(getHistory())
            .then(response => {
                let history = response;
                this.setState({
                    historyList : history
                });
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

When I look at the response it has right data but gives error in

```
this.setState({ historyList : history });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you cross check if another page is having `return`? tbh I've never used nor seen `return` in `componentWillMount`

Comment: Can you show the rest of the module? Are you sure the error is not thrown before setting state? As an aside, this operation is likely a better fit for `componentDidMount`. Added bonus will be getting past the render blocking error you're seeing